# Вывести несколько значений SQL в PHP

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Как одним запросом `SQL` вывести несколько значений из строк, одного столбца, то есть допустим есть таблица `users`, в ней `id`. Как вывести все `id`, используя `php`, на `SQL` это так:

```
SELECT id FROM users;
```

А на PHP в массиве остается только нулевой индекс, то есть первое найденное значение:

```
$x777=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users",$db);
$myrow777 = mysql_fetch_array($x777);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно просто вызывать mysql_fetch_array() до потери пульса.

```
$x777=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users",$db);
while($myrow777 = mysql_fetch_array($x777)){
      echo $myrow777['id']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Нет, там я как-то по другому делал, то есть если в таблице 3 значения массив был такой:
0 - первое значение
1 - второе
2 - третье

Comment: >Нет, там я как-то по другому делал, то есть если в таблице 3 значения массив был такой: 0 - первое значение 1 - второе 2 - третье

Объясняйте конкретнее, что Вы хотите? Возможно, вы говорите про функцию `mysql_result()`


Comment: вот точно, спасибо